Weyl group of $D_n$
We have that the root system of the Dynkin diagram of type $D_n$ can be realized by considering the standard inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the vectors $\{e_1 - e_2, \ldots, e_{n-1} - e_n, e_{n-1} + e_n \}$. Determine its Weyl group.
I did it this way: consider ${a_1, \ldots, a_n}$ as the simple roots of $D_n$ and define the reflection $s_i(v) = v - B(a_i, v)a_i$ where $B$ is the bilinear form associated with the incidence matrix of $D_n$. By considering the root system in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard inner product and the vectors $\{e_1 - e_2, \ldots, e_{n-1} - e_n, e_{n-1} + e_n \}$, $s_i$ with respect to this system swaps the $i$-th coordinate with the $i+1$-th coordinate for each $i = 1, \ldots, n-1$ and is therefore isomorphic to $S_n$, while $s_n$ swaps the $(n-1)$-th coordinate and the $n$-th coordinate and changes their signs, thus $S_2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. I'm not sure if this is correct; if anyone can confirm, thanks.
